# Backup iPhone 6s failed

Tags: iphone, backup

The goal is to move all the data from iPhone 6s to iPhone 7, but all those options failed:

- backup to laptop
- backup to iCloud
- direct data transfer

I'm trying to make a backup of my iPhone 6s (ios 15.7.8) using my MacBook Pro M1 (macOS 13.5.1) and continuously receiving error "Could not back up the iPhone “iPhone” because an error occurred.".

Trying to backup to iCloud ends with the same error.
In the iPhone's logs I've found `BackupAgent2` entries:

```
Finished scanning domain CameraRollDomain - size:105361783/94/12800301, files:396, dirs:368, clones:0/7/1, hardLinks:0, symLinks:0: Error Domain=MBErrorDomain Code=101 UserInfo={NSFilePath=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
...
Failed to preflight: Error Domain=MBErrorDomain Code=101 UserInfo={NSFilePath=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
```

Before that, I found the similar entries in the logs but regarding to Facebook domain and then Viber, so I re-installed those applications and related to them errors disappeared from the logs.
But it seems that there is no option to re-install camera-related application.

How to get rid of that error? Is it the root cause of the problem?